# Make MySQL not to convert string to number

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes, type-conversion

I have a query in my application that selects users from a table by ID or by username:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$x' OR username = '$x'
```

This is working when given usernames like `foo`, `bar123` or ids like `1`, `123`.
But when I give a username like `2foo` it selects both user `2foo` and user with `id=2`. So it takes the `2` of `2foo` and finds a user. Additionally I get a warning message: *1292: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 2foo*.

Is there a way to tell MySQL not to do this conversion (for this query but not whole db)? Or do I need to do a filtering after the query to discard false results?

Comment: Could you share the relevant piece of code that builds the actual query? This is most likely not a problem in mysql, but in the generated question.

Comment: I entered this query into MySQL Query Browser: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '2foo' OR username = '2foo'`. There is no surrounding code as I identified this query as the problematic one from my application. MySQL-Version: 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10

Comment: The correct thing to do would be to check if $x is a number and build your query accordingly:`if(is_numeric($x)){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $x OR username = '$x'"
} else {
  $safeX = mysql_real_escape_string($x); // Or prepared statements, or whatever else you prefer.
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$x'"
}`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you do if a user enrolls with username '123' ?

Comment: @JoryGeerts that is my solution now, thank you very much for your ideas (post it as an answer to get upvotes)

Comment: @pilcrow usernames have to have at least one character [a-zA-Z], that is already given

Comment: OK, that in mind you ought to avoid solutions that rely solely on PHP's `is_numeric()`, which permits ambiguous username/id matches like '0xFF' and '1e4'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query is formed in a way, that triggers a "this-is-a-feature-not-a-bug" behaviour in MySQL: You compare the same string ('$x') to a numeric field (id) and to a varchar field (username).

While I am sure, there are ways to make this work in SQL, I suspect the only correct way is to fix the PHP that creates the query. Something like

```
if (is_numeric($x)) $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$x' OR username = '$x'";
else $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$x'";
```

should help.

Here is the SQL version, just for the sake of completeness:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = IF('$x' REGEXP '^[0-9]+$','$x',0) OR username = '$x'
```

Note: Form the OQ I assume, that $x is already escaped.

Comment: (1) That REGEXP will match '2foo' — you need to anchor it on both ends.  (2) I'd suggest `IF(val REGEXP ..., val, NULL)`, since there might be an `id` that equals zero in the OP's table, but there won't be an id that equals NULL.

Comment: My bad, fixed the regex. As for the 0/Null I am quite sure the users table has id int auto_increment ...

Comment: how can you be sure?  Did you see the OP's DDL?  What about [NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero), precisely for storing zeroes in AUTO_INCREMENT columns?

Comment: I can't be sure! But from the OQ's tone and content I assume the OP will be able to adapt the SQL to whatever he needs, if (and only if) he choses not to go with my suggestion to fix the PHP

Comment: @EugenRieck @pilcrow I used your suggestion to distinguish by is_numeric/is_string.  Using an `if` having two SQL queries with a index on each queried column is faster than using a regex I think, also it is cleaner code. The ID is indeed the auto-incremented primary key. "this-is-a-feature-not-a-bug-but-none-the-less-throws-a-warning" ;-)